# filtering a ManyToMany field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm going to explain my problem using the example in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), in which the relationship between the members of a band is represented with 3 models:

> Person => Membership <= Group

A basic example query is

```
# Find all the groups with a member whose name starts with 'Paul'
>>> band = Group.objects.filter(members__name__startswith='Paul')
>>> band
[<Group: The Beatles>]
```

This is correct, and if I check the members of the result set I get this:

```
>>> band.first().members.all()
[<Person: Ringo Starr>, <Person: Paul McCartney>]
```

Is it possible to filter the Group model in such a way the queryset(e.g. `band`) only contains `<Person: Paul McCartney>` i.e. The instances that comply with the filter?

Comment: do you mean groups that contains specific person or only contains specific person? If a group contains Paul McCartney and another person, do you want also that group?

Comment: It doesn't have to be exclusively the filtered Person, so if I filter for Paul I will get the beatles, but given that I filtered by 'Paul' I would like to get group "The beatles" but if I check the members of the returned instance, I don't want to include 'Ringo' because it doesn't comply with the existing filter.

Comment: Each filter is applied individually.  Therefore,  if you get Beatles after first filter and check it's members,  it will show all of the members because you get the whole object from previous filter.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that logic, it makes sense, however I would like to get it working in the way I described, mainly because I have serializer for the parent model (e.g. Group) and I want to reflect the filter on the same type of document.